# Looping through JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to loop through game details using the ESPN API. However I am only able to return the first `event`. I would like it to return all events. The print section also only return the first event info as well.

```
        response = requests.get(JSON_URL)
        json_data = response.json() 
        game_status = []
        home_team = []
        home_score = []
        away_team = []
        away_score = []

        for event in json_data['events']:
            if event['season']['type'] == 2:
                print(event['season']['type'],
                      event['competitions'][0]['competitors'][0]['team']['abbreviation'],
                      event['competitions'][0]['competitors'][0]['score'],
                      event['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['team']['abbreviation'],
                      event['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['score'],
                      event['competitions'][0]['status']['type']['shortDetail'])
                

            for games in json_data['events']:
                    home_team.append(games['competitions'][0]['competitors'][0]['team']['abbreviation'])
                    home_score.append(games['competitions'][0]['competitors'][0]['score'])
                    away_team.append(games['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['team']['abbreviation'])
                    away_score.append(games['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['score'])
                    game_status.append(games['competitions'][0]['status']['type']['shortDetail'])
        
            data = { 
               #'home_team':home_team,
               #'home_score': home_score,
               #'away_team': away_team,
               #'away_score': away_score,
               #'game_status': game_status,
               'seasontype' : 2,
               'scoreboard' : {'home_team': home_team, 'home_score': home_score, 'away_team': away_team , 'away_score': away_score , 'game_status': game_status}
            } 
           
            return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The Return:

```
18/Dec/2022 23:28:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[{'name': 'ARI @ DEN', 'date': '2022-12-18T21:05Z', 'hometeam': 'DEN', 'homeid': '7', 'homescore': 24, 'awayteam': 'ARI', 'awayid': '22', 'awayscore': 15, 'down': None, 'spot': None, 'time': '0:00', 'quarter': 4, 'over': True, 'redzone': None, 'possession': None, 'state': 'post'}]
```

I would like the code loop through each event but it’s only returning the first event. The return above on lists the first game in the list.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a simple example of what `json_data` looks like. Also, shouldn't your second, nested for loop to get `games` be looping through `event`, not through the same `json_data['events']` from your outer for loop? I suspect that is your problem as you can get weird results like this with nested loops over the same object.

Comment: in addition to what @frederick-douglas-pearce the function is only returning the first set of data because the return statement is inside of the first `for` loop so after all of the steps complete in the the first iteration the data is sent from the that function back to where you are using it. if you want all of the data you should unindent `return jsonify(data)` by one spacing and properly add `data` to a list that you can then jasonify and send the result back to your previous function.

Comment: yeah, @AndrewRyan's comment about the `return` statement is definitely the problem. If you provide an example of `json_data`, I'm happy to look more closely.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong output. The json output with the above code is something like.

{"scoreboard":"away_score":"28","20","26","17","20","15","10","13","10","27","25","40","10","0","33","24"],"away_team":"BUF","NYG","NE","TB","CIN","HOU","CHI","ATL","DEN","BAL","LAC","LV","LAR","NO","GB","PIT"].

So it is iterating but the formatting is off. I would like it to iterated and be something Iike  "away_team" PHI "away_score" 23. Not print out the entire away_score array for example.

Thanks